# spring boot + validacion con hibernate retorna MethodConstraintViolationImpl

Tags: spring-boot, nhibernate

Hola estoy trabajando con spring boot 1.5.21.RELEASE creando un servicio rest y tratando de agregar validaciones para atraparlas en una clase @ControllerAdvice, el problema es cuando da un error de validacion el servicio me retorna un MethodConstraintViolationImpl y no un ConstraintViolationException, como puedo hacer que spring retorne el error y no hibernate